# Why is __main__ name presented as a reason for forbidding relative imports?

Tags: python, python-import, python-packaging

Hopefully it's not a duplicate.

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

> Note that relative imports are based on the name of the current module. Since the name of the main module is always "`__main__`", modules intended for use as the main module of a Python application must always use absolute imports.

I understand I can only use relative imports from within an imported package;

but here they seem to present the name `__main__` as the reason for why the main module must use absolute imports.

I mean, I can also have 3 modules (`first.py`, second and third) in a single dir, the first one can import the second and the second, while having `__name__ == second` (not `__main__`) still won't be able to use relative imports to import the third.

So, is there any logic in the reason they're providing? Or is it just a flaw in the spec?..

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what your question is. Can you clarify what you are confused about? If `first.py`, `second.py` and `third.py` are in a subpackage then yes they can use relative imports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's out of date. That text predates [PEP 366](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/), which enables relative import support in the `__main__` module.

That text has been in the tutorial in close to its current form since [Python 2.5](https://docs.python.org/release/2.5/tut/node8.html#SECTION008420000000000000000). PEP 366 went in in Python 2.6, but no one realized that the tutorial section was obsolete.

---

Note that a `__main__` module can only use relative imports if Python considers it part of a package. That usually means you have to run it with [`python -m`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m). Running a file by file path will cause Python to treat it as a top-level module instead of a package submodule.

For example, if I have a directory `blah` with files `__init__.py`, `foo.py`, and `bar.py` in it, and `foo.py` contains

```
from . import bar
```

and I run `python foo.py` from inside the `blah` directory, or `python blah/foo.py` from above the `blah` directory, then `foo.py` is not considered part of a package, and the relative import will fail.

On the other hand, if `blah` is findable as a package (because I've installed it, or because I'm running Python from the directory above the `blah` directory), and I do `python -m blah.foo` to tell Python to run the `blah.foo` module as the main module, then `blah.foo` will be considered part of the `blah` package, and the relative import will succeed.